# Custom sign in for Simperium IOS

Tags: simperium

I am tryin to use Simperium through IOS. But I have an obvious problem. I dont want to use the built-in `LoginViewController`. So, for that reason, I am using Post method for POST `https://auth.simperium.com/1/{app_id}/authorize/` and authorize the app and get back access token.

But after getting access token when I set it in SPUser instance and add SPUser instance to Simperium, I get :

> Simperium didn't find an existing auth token.**

Here is the code :

```
simperium = [[Simperium alloc]initWithRooViewController:window.rootViewController];
[simperium enableManualAuthentication];
SPUser *spUser = [[SPUser alloc]initWithEmail:email token:accessToken]; //received accesstoken from Postmethod 
[simperium setUser:spUser];
[simperium startWithAppID:@"" .....];
```

Answer (score 1):

See the "iosupdate" branch for [the Simperium repository on GitHub](https://github.com/Simperium/simperium) and the [related discussion](https://github.com/Simperium/simperium/issues/23). You'll find that the easiest way to customize the flow in this branch is to create your own subclass of `SPLoginViewController`, and then you don't need to worry about the networking side of things.